# Laying out a grid using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm confused about the behaviour I'm getting when using Bootstrap.  [This page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) seems to imply that if I want a 3x3 grid, I could use something similar to the following (taken directly from the page):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col align-self-start">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col align-self-center">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col align-self-end">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, when I tried this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col align-self-center">
            <img src="~/images/UpArrow.png" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col align-self-start">
            <img src="~/images/LeftArrow.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col align-self-center">
            <img src="~/images/Background.png" />
            <textarea>test</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col align-self-end">
            <img src="~/images/RightArrow.png" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col align-self-center">
            <img src="~/images/DownArrow.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The arrow images simply lined up above one another.  I have managed to get this to behave as I want, using this method:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="~/images/UpArrow.png" />
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="~/images/LeftArrow.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="~/images/Background.png" />
            <textarea>test</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="~/images/RightArrow.png" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>

        <div class="col align-self-center">
            <img src="~/images/DownArrow.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is: why did my initial attempt not work?  Also, is the way that I've ended up with, the best (or only way) to achieve this.

Comment: Question is: What layout do you actually want? Because what you ended up with has nothing to do with 3x3. It's a big mess, that's for sure. But no 3x3. So, what do you want?

Comment: You are referring to the third snippet as "I have managed to get this to behave as I want". OK. But how is this supposed to be a 3x3 grid? Nowhere near 3x3 there.

Comment: The example from Bootstrap docs is clearly a 3x1 grid, not 3x3. Please clarify the question.

Comment: @WebDevBooster It probably is a mess (I'm clearly not too experienced using bootstrap).  What I want is effectively a cross, where the image and textbox sit in the centre, and the arrow images are placed in their respective positions to the left, right, top and bottom of the image.  Whilst what I have may not, technically be a 3x3 grid, it's as much of the grid as I need: sorry this was not clear.

Comment: @ZimSystem I agree - the example from Bootstrap does not look like a 3x3 grid to me, either.  However, if you have a look at the site, there is a grid displayed next to that code sample that appears (to my untrained eye) to be a 3x3 grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Understanding Bootstrap

Using the `col` gives the element the attributes of a column without explicitly setting a width. This will result in each column narrowing (or growing) to accommodate all other columns in the row (if there are no columns it will take up the entire row).

In your provided example that works you're using `col-md-3`, breaking it down you have the `col` object, then the breakpoint `md`, and the set width (or number of column spaces out of 12) of `3`. This means that any screen width over `md` will result in this div being a 3 column width element.

If you want it to act as this grid all the time (including small screens ie. phones) I'd recommend changing the classes to `col-3`. Removing the breakpoint tells it to act as a 3 column element always. Additionally you could improve the first and last sections by using the `mr-auto` & `ml-auto` classes to get them centered and remove the empty div.

Bootstrap takes a bit to get used to, but once you get a hang of the class system it makes sense.

---

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 mr-auto ml-auto">
            UP
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-4">
            LEFT
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            CENTER
            <textarea>test</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            RIGHT
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 mr-auto ml-auto">
            DOWN
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Comment: I was going to query exactly what "mr-auto" and "al-auto" do that causes this to centralise; but having tried your suggestion, it reverts to displaying everything in a single column.

Comment: `mr-auto` and `ml-auto` set the margin explicitly to auto which results in a column being centered and makes it so that invisible columns don't have to be inserted to push content over. I've just updated the answer to use `col-4` as the class for a 3column grid should be 4 not 3 (12 / 3 = 4). As for it displaying in a single column, not sure what to tell you as it seems to be working just fine...I've updated the block above so that you can run the snippet.

Comment: the one below shows up in a single column b/c of the use of the `md` breakpoint. You'll have to view it in full screen to see it as you're wanting.

Comment: I was using v 3.3.7 that comes with a new VS .Net Core project... as soon as I added the link to 4, it burst into life.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a cross-like layout for medium (md) screens and above, then there is a slightly more efficient way to achieve that because in that case you only need one div for the top and bottom rows. Using the `justify-content-center` class on those rows will horizontally center the columns like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center border">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" style="font-size: 55px;"></i>
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center text-md-right border">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left" style="font-size: 55px;"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center border">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/57" />
            <div class="w-100"></div>
            <textarea>test</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center text-md-left border">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" style="font-size: 55px;"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center border">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down" style="font-size: 55px;"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks to the use of responsive text alignment classes (such as `text-center text-md-right` etc.) everything will stack neatly on top of each other when collapsed into a single column on screens smaller than `md`.

It's also possible to remove certain elements on smaller screens by using responsive `d-none` classes (d-none means "display:none").

`<div class="w-100"></div>` is just a divider making sure the elements stack nicely on top of each other. `w-100` means "width:100%".

The reason your initial approach didn't work is because you hadn't used the `justify-content-center` class on the rows. That's a flexbox class for horizontally centering the items inside.